# metamask can't connect to local testnet in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

I am using geth 1.7.3 stable,  I have tried the following commands.

```
geth --rinkeby --ws --wsport=8546 --wsorigins="*" --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --cache=512 --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network" --rpcport=8545 --fast --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303
```

in the first begining

```
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Loaded most recent local header          number=1219706 hash=8114e4…01dc09 td=10746707923789321578
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0       hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=1203408 hash=255f31…0cba4a td=10416051820938618909
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=98
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [01-01|12:45:07] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface=NAT-PMP(192.168.1.1)
INFO [01-01|12:45:08] UDP listener up                          self=enode://841b29cdefa12ddbcc2569bb61729338100a365cf2f151f966cfd43b757d986b8b7f99d8d55090f00917307a2f713bb8e5d9bbb2fa91f4a18093b0a45e2cf1c2@82.7.211.112:30303
INFO [01-01|12:45:08] WebSocket endpoint opened: ws://127.0.0.1:8546 
INFO [01-01|12:45:08] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://841b29cdefa12ddbcc2569bb61729338100a365cf2f151f966cfd43b757d986b8b7f99d8d55090f00917307a2f713bb8e5d9bbb2fa91f4a18093b0a45e2cf1c2@82.7.211.112:30303
```

it continuously gives me this information

```
INFO [01-01|12:39:07] Generated ethash verification cache      epoch=2 elapsed=3.111s
INFO [01-01|12:39:07] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=483.670ms number=37120 hash=a27938…2d697f ignored=0
INFO [01-01|12:39:08] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=518.097ms number=39168 hash=1a1cd2…514d2d ignored=0
INFO [01-01|12:39:08] Imported new state entries
```

wondering the continuous message is meaning the node is at the sync?

during the time, i used the metamask to connect the localhost:8545, but it can't connect to it, anything wrong with my commands?

Comment: "but it can't connect to it" Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? If not, how do you know MetaMask can't connect?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://support.metamask.io/kb/article/2-using-a-local-node:

```
Geth needs to have a special CORS setting enabled to allow MetaMask to connect to it by default, so try starting it with this command:

`geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain="chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn"`
```

In your case, I would suggest just adding the `--rpccorsdomain="...` parameter.